# How do I keep a certain number of digits in a double in Visual Basic

Tags: vb6

I am trying to display a double so it will always have 4 digits after the decimal point. For example, one double would be 0.0182, and another 0.0180. However, my problem occurs when the double ends in 0, which results in truncating the zero and leaving 0.018. I'm trying to add on a zero at the end of my number to fix this, but receiving a syntax error.

```
Dim minFeature As Double
```

...

```
minFeature = Round(minFeature, 4) ' keep only 4 digits of precision. works.
minFeature = CDbl(CStr(minFeature).PadRight(1, "0")) ' add on an extra 0. does not work.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will return the number as a string and preserve four decimal places.

```
Format(minFeature, "0.0000")
```

For more information, see the [docs on `Format()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa241719(v=vs.60).aspx).

Comment: I am printing it to screen, so I guess it could be done as an integer or String.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to include the portion of your comment starting with `[code]`, and remove the question you've asked for clarification. Anything posted in the "Your Answer" area should be an answer to the question. If you need more details, you'll have to wait until you've earned sufficient privileges to post comments (currently 50), and then you can ask in a comment to the question itself. Thanks.

Comment: I suggest using `Format$()` instead of the Variant `Format()` function, which is probably only accepted by the compiler to make it easier to import VBScript or something.  Type 1 extra character and gain performance - which really adds up in some programs.  Also a link to the VB6 documentation article would be better than the VB.Net article actually linked above.